# UIAutomator - setText in editText not work

Tags: junit, android-edittext, flutter, settext, android-uiautomator

I have developed a Flutter chat. Now I am trying to do test with UI automator but setText method for Edit Text not work.
[UI Automator Viewer app](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HXOpTUa.png)

This is for a Windows 10 with Android Studio.

I have a class where I define the objects

```
public class ChatAppObjects {
    public static UiObject ICON_CHATAPP = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").text("ChatApp"));
    public static UiObject TXT_MESSAGE = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText"));
    public static UiObject BTN_SEND = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.Button"));
}
```

And this is the test

```
public void test1() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance();
    mDevice.pressHome();
    ChatAppObjects.ICON_CHATAPP.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
    ChatAppObjects.TXT_MESSAGE.click();
    ChatAppObjects.TXT_MESSAGE.clearTextField();
    ChatAppObjects.TXT_MESSAGE.setText("Prueba");
    ChatAppObjects.BTN_SEND.click();
}
```

Test run successful but not write "Prueba" into textbox

Answer (score 0):

Flutter apps do not work with UiAutomator. The only way to run integration tests on them right now is with flutter's own testing utility. You can read about getting started with it [here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction).

Comment: Thanks you so match!